# SQL sum of maxes of each occurrence

Tags: mysql, sql, sum, max

I have the following table:

```
category    id  date    views
1           3   5-1-17  40
1           3   5-2-17  70
1           3   5-3-17  110
1           3   5-4-17  200
1           5   5-1-17  50
1           5   5-2-17  75
2           6   4-1-17  90
2           6   4-2-17  95
2           9   4-3-17  115
2           9   6-5-17  125
2           9   6-6-17  135
```

How do I sum the max `views` for each `id` by `category`?

The resulting pull should look like this:

```
category    views
1           275 
2           230
```

For `category` 1, the max `views` for `id` 3 is 200 and the max `views` for `id` 5 is 75. The sum for `category` 1 is thus 275.

For `category` 2, the max `views` for `id` 6 is 95 and the max `views` for `id` 9 is 135. The sum for `category` 2 is thus 230.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use two levels of aggregation:

```
select category, sum(max_views)
from (select category, id, max(views) as max_views
      from t
      group by category, id
     ) t
group by category;
```

You can also use `row_number()` here:

```
select category, sum(max_views)
from (select t.*,
             row_number() over (partition by category, id, order by views desc) as seqnum
      from t
     ) t
where seqnum = 1
group by category;
```

It would be interesting which is faster.  I would vote on the double aggregation, but that might not always be true.